# I need to fire a "change" event at the init of an Alpine.js component

Tags: javascript, dom-events, alpine.js

I'm new to Alpine.js and I'm struggling with this simple task.
I have two select in a form. I populate the first with a JS script then when the user select a value the script populate the second select.

My problem is that when an user come back on the same form after a submit
I need to fire a change event on the first select to have the second ready for the value I have to select.

Here my code.
I get this.$refs.select_one.change is not a function
Thank you for your help

```
<div x-data="load_form()" x-init="init">

    <form>
        <select name="first" x-ref="select_one" x-model="first_select"></select>
        <select name="second" x-model="second_select"></select>
    </form>

</div>

function load_form() {
    return {
        first_select: "",
        second_select: "",            
        init() {
            script_that_populate_selects("#select1", "#select2");
            // set the first
            this.first_select = "value1";
            // this should fire the change event
            this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.select_one.change());
            // wait before set the second value
            setTimeout(()=> {
                this.second_select = "value2";
            }, 1500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood my fault
This is the right instruction to fire a change event

```
this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.select_one.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
```